# Fully featured web media player to handle online media library (focus on music)

Tags: php, jquery, media-player, mp3, playlist

The concept is to consolidate my friends' and my MP3 collections, providing backup and remote access to media.

- I will give them ftp access to upload their libraries.
- A password protected site with different accounts (this will be handled with PHP).
- A simple media player - mainly focused on music, videos welcome but not mandatory.
- A good and fast file browser with indexing capabilities for fast searches.
- Playlist saving capability. With option to see each other's playlists.
- Cross platform, to be able to access it from mobile devices etc.

Seeing there are solutions around I thought I could ask for something ready in order to avoid writing it from scratch. I was thinking this should be two different things, a file browser combined with a media player.

Is there some code that will provide both the media player and the file browser already available or should go looking for two different things? I know there are similar questions but I wanted to get an up-to-date answer on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short answer to all of your points:

- You don't need to give them access via FTP, there are tons of scripts to handle uploading and browsing files on a server, together with permissions. [elFinder](http://elfinder.org/) is a very good script
- There are a lot of articles on user authentication. PHP has one [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php), and you can find already made scripts to use or reference, like [uLogin](http://ulogin.sourceforge.net/) and [UserPie](http://userpie.com/)
- You could use the jQuery-based [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/). It can be used as a media player / media library for videos and audio. [Here's an example](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-video/) from their page that includes playlist functionality.
- You can use elFinder as a file browser, as mentioned above
- Since they will have a common place where they'll be uploading files, you can just configure jPlayer to switch to each user's folder
- All of the above are based on web technologies, so they all should work on modern mobile devices. You will need to follow a [responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) approach.

Comment: thank you filippos, lots of stuff to look into